# How do I set irregular intervals on x-axis in plot()?

Tags: plot

I have data from which I created a plot with lines. The values of each sample accord to a temperature (e.g. "C300cum").

I tried to put "axis" at different intervals.

```
  plot(t(as.matrix(RC_means_DF[c("D2Aa"),14:18])),type="l, xaxt = 'n')
  axis(1, at = c(1,2, 2.5,4,7), labels = c("300", "400", "450", "600", 
  "900"))
```

But I do not know how to do this within the plot function so the x-values adjust to that position.  I also could not find an answer to this here.

```
C300cum   C400cum   C450cum   C600cum  C900cum
D2Aa  0.3900000 0.9753333 1.2246667 1.6066667 1.693667
D2Ab  0.5470000 1.2103333 1.4473333 1.9603333 2.065667
D2Ac  0.4660000 1.0146667 1.2213333 1.6906667 1.807667
D2Ba  0.4646667 1.0573333 1.2920000 1.9376667 2.069333
D2Bb  0.4810000 1.1026667 1.3450000 1.9210000 2.115667


plot(t(as.matrix(RC_means_DF[c("D2Aa"),14:18])),type="l"
 , ylim = c(0.4,2.5), xaxt = 'n')
lines(t(as.matrix(RC_means_DF["D2Aab",1:5])))
lines(t(as.matrix(RC_means_DF["D2Ac",1:5])))
lines(t(as.matrix(RC_means_DF["D2Ba",1:5])))
lines(t(as.matrix(RC_means_DF["D2Bb",1:5])))
```

I want, that the intervals between the individual sample values accord to the true intervals of the temperature scale, i.e. accordingly less between 300 and 450 than e.g. 450 - 500.

In the end-effect I'd liek to have irregular intervals on the x-axis

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer... just explain the individual values by "concatenated" numbers...

```
plot(t(as.matrix(RC_means_DF[c("D2Aa"),14:18]))~ c(1,2,2.5,4,7),type="l"
, ylim = c(0.4,2.5), ylab = "%C burned", 
xlab = "temperature °C", xaxt = 'n')
axis(1, at = c(1,2,2.5, 4,7), labels = c("300", "400", "450", "600", "900"))
lines(t(as.matrix(RC_means_DF["D3Aa",14:18]))~ c(1,2,2.5,4,7))
lines(t(as.matrix(RC_means_DF["D5sAa",14:18]))~ c(1,2,2.5,4,7))
lines(t(as.matrix(RC_means_DF["D9nAa",14:18]))~ c(1,2,2.5,4,7))
```

gave me a plot with desired spacing (those aren't same values as in the original post).

[image]